# startActivityForResult returns the correct result, but then it becomes null

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, startactivityforresult

I have a startActivityForResult that is returning a username. This code inside the `onActivityResult` is returning the fresh username as evidenced by the log function returning it.

```
// return user initials from popup
 setUsername(intent.getStringExtra("USERNAME"));
 Log.d("ME", "Username is now :" + getUsername()); //returning the real result
```

After the result comes back to MainActivity, I have a shared preferences function that reads from getUsername();

```
SharedPreferences sp = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        setUsername(sp.getString("USERNAME", ""));
```

This is only returning `""` instead of what was supposed to be written to `setUsername()`. For reference, my methods are:

```
private void setUsername(String name) {
    username = name;
}

private String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

// called during onDestroy()
void write() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("USERNAME", getUsername());
    editor.putBoolean("FIRST_RUN", firstRun);
    editor.apply();
}

// called during onStart()
void read() {
    SharedPreferences sp = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    setUsername(sp.getString("USERNAME", ""));
    firstRun = sp.getBoolean("FIRST_RUN", true);
}
```

And in the other class I'm writing the username to shared preferences with this:

```
private void write() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("USERNAME", etInitials.getText().toString());
    editor.apply();
}
```

Comment: You aren't calling write in the code you show us, so you're not actually putting it in shared preference.

Comment: Edited to clarify when read() and write() are called

Answer (score 1):

```
SharedPreferences sp = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    setUsername(sp.getString("USERNAME", ""));
```

you do realize that the second line is setting a value right, therefore instead of getting the name you set it.

```
void write() {
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("USERNAME", getUsername());
editor.putBoolean("FIRST_RUN", firstRun);
editor.apply();
}
```

the above methods needs to be called first,with this `intent.getStringExtra("USERNAME")`

Comment: the thing is you are not calling write, so the value of a default string is always empty that is your results are empty.

Comment: you are initially getting the value before setting it, to demonstrate this, declare the variable with a set value, try it again?

Comment: I'm calling `read()` during `onStart()`. The shared preferences should be done by the time I pull up the activity for result. I will try will a separate value and see if that's causing the flaw.

Comment: the problem lies in the chain of imperative calls executed.

Comment: The second line should set a default value if there isn't a "USERNAME" field found in the shared preferences, right?

Comment: if i am right , when the results get returned , the first thing you want is to parse the intent then store it in a preference file right or wroing

Comment: That is exactly what worked. I called the `write()` function during the `onActivityResult()'. This answer will be accepted if you add that in.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the "other class" is calling the write method during the onDestroy, the onActivityResult on the main activity will be called first:

```
OtherActivity   >>> onPause
MainActivity    >>> onActivityResult
MainActivity    >>> onRestart
MainActivity    >>> onStart
MainActivity    >>> onResume
MainActivity    >>> onPostResume
OtherActivity   >>> onStop
OtherActivity   >>> onDestroy
```

Comment: Thank you for the order of operations. This clarified the other answer of writing to the preferences during the `onActivityResult` phase.